# How to dynamically support different languages for .NET applications?

Tags: asp.net, .net, localization, translation

I have a .NET application. Where language specific resources files, some JS file are used for showing language specific pages when user changes any language.

But What I want is to do it more it dynamically.

- Create these resources file/content and keep it in DB
- Allow user to provide interface for uploading the translations for that specific pages.

Could you guide how to proceed with this?
What are the approaches to make it dynamic?
What are the industry standard/best practices for this?

Thought of putting Content into database language specific, but want to check how dynamically it will update, when we put the translations to DB.